# How to keep the styles of Polygon when creating KML in Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

When i write the features to KML. It doesn't include the styles of features. A [similiar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17031/openlayers-format-kml-write-style) is asked for openlayers 2. I want the code for openlayers 3. Following is the code for writing the features to the kml file

```
 var drfeatures = drawLayerSource.getFeatures();
 var format = new ol.format.KML();
 var kml = format.writeFeatures(drfeatures, {featureProjection:'EPSG:3857'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add style object to the ol.format.KML();

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'city.kml',
    format: new ol.format.KML({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        extractStyles: false
    })
});

function styleFunction(feature) {
    var style = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'red',
        width: 4
        })
    })
    return [style];
}

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: styleFunction
});
map.addLayer(layer);
```